# Android Multiple packages and Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build an Android app with multiple package name for better structure. My current package is `src/com/waveletandroid`.

I have made a folder under `src/com/waveletandroid/customer` and created `SearchCustomerActivity.java` inside this folder. Also created a new folder in `res/layout/customer`. `activity_search_customer.xml` file has been created inside this res/layout/customer folder.

Now when I am trying to build the project it's throwing error "R cannot be resolved as variable".

Comment: i think its because you have create the customer folder in the layout folder. Try to put the xml in the layout folder itself.

Comment: The layout folder can not contain sub folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with your resource files.

This will result in not generating R.java, which leads to "**R cannot be resolved as variable**".

The origin of this error is *creating folders within the layout folder*. This is not allowed by Android. The usage of multiple packages is supported and is advisable to do.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I have to organize all my xml layout files in res/layout directory? I can't organize by creating different directory for different module?

Comment: My package name is package="com.waveletandroid" <activity
            android:name=".customer.SearchCustomerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_customer" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.waveletandroid.SearchItemActivity" > is my activity. Still showing "R cannot be resolved as variable"

Comment: Thanks. Now it has been solved after import the com.waveletandroid.R